# Make UIButton repeat animation on condition

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` hooked up to an action that does this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(squareOneMover) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
[self theLoop];
```

This is the code for `squareOneMover` (`squareOne` is a `UIButton`):

```
- (void)squareOneMover {
    [self.squareOne setHidden:NO];
    CGPoint originalPosition = self.squareOne.center;
    originalPosition.y = -55;
    [self.squareOne setCenter:originalPosition];
    CGPoint position = self.squareOne.center;
    position.y += 790;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         [self.squareOne setCenter:position];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL complete) {
                         if (complete) {
                             if (self.squareOne.hidden==YES) {
                                 [self squareOneMover];
                             }
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
```

Note: When the square is pressed it get hidden

What the app is supposed to do:

[image: Concept of the app]

I've got that all working now thanks to Daniel T. The above code works great

Comment: Why are you calling squareOneMover twice?

Comment: @DanielT. One, so that the animation begins, and the other is so that the if statement resets the animation and does it.

Comment: Well running the animation twice might explain why you see it going twice as fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll talk you through the solution... First, you want to write a method that snaps the button to the start position, and then animates it to the end position. You almost have that already, you just need to put the bit at the beginning to snap the button to the start position.

Next, you want to use an NSTimer to call that method every X seconds. Another option would be to put a completion block on the animation that restarts the animation (by calling the method) if the button is still visible.

Last, you want to make an IBAction connected to the button. The action should invalidate the timer (if you went the timer route) and hide the button.

Have at, and if you have trouble with the code, post what you have here and ask for help again.

Comment: That's half of what I want. Can u add in more code that makes the animation repeat itself when the `squareOne` is hidden?

Comment: What would be the point of animating the movement of squareOne when it is hidden?

Comment: When `squareOne` is animating it isn't hidden. It's a button so when it is pressed to will become hidden. Upon doing so, it will restart the animation and show `squareOne`

Comment: @Spoof said, "It's a button so when it is pressed to will become hidden." Why does it become hidden when pressed? That isn't standard behavior. What is the exact goal here? Maybe you could add some sketches of what is supposed to happen to the question...

Comment: Added a quick little sketch

Comment: For an added bonus, figure out how to make the button move back and forth rather than snapping back. Good luck!

Comment: Just wondering, when you say snap, do you mean `UISnapBehaviour`?

Comment: No, I mean set the center of the button without embedding the set in an animation block.

Comment: I did what you said and it works great! Thanks btw. But now I want to do something else I originally didn't put in the question, because I though it would be easy to implement. Can you check my edited question and see if you have the solution?

Comment: I think it would be best to start a new question.